# How can I type RTL in textbox at customtkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, text, textbox, customtkinter

This is a wrong text:

```
text = "سلام s4 خراب است"
```

and true text must be:

```
text = "خراب است s4 سلام"
```

I wrote the text in the photo in Office Word, and it is true this way. rtl must be mix with ltr.

Answer (score 0):

To enable right-to-left (RTL) support for Tkinter and CustomTkinter, I recommend utilizing the [AwesomeTkinter](https://pypi.org/project/AwesomeTkinter/) library. This library offers numerous features, including bidirectional support for RTL languages.

Here is an example utilizing the `awesometkinter.bidirender.render_text` function on your provided sample `text`:

```
import customtkinter
from awesometkinter.bidirender import render_text


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master=self, width=400, font=('Tahoma', 20))
        self.textbox.tag_config("right", justify=customtkinter.RIGHT)
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.textbox.insert("0.0", render_text("سلام s4 خراب است"), "right")


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

And here is the result I obtained:

[image]

Comment: Hello، Mr. AliReza 
I have a problem when typing in textbox that is wrong the same answer you if we delete and write again write wrong that does not solve my problem please give me an answer for this problem thank you

Comment: @AliTny Is it possible for you to use `CTkEntry` instead of `CTkTextbox`? The [AwesomeTkinter](https://pypi.org/project/AwesomeTkinter/) library offers support for the `add_bidi_support` function, which can address the issue you mentioned with the `Entry` and `Label` widgets. If you are able to make the switch to `CTkEntry`, I can enhance my answer accordingly.